# Select Distinct and Count on the same query MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a table products, and each product has a specific brand.

What I want to do is to count the times a specific brand has appeared and, together, show the unique product it has.

For example:

Table products

```
ID, ProductName, Brand
1, TV, Samsung
2, TV, Sony
3, TV, Samsung
4, Phone, Sony
```

The query should result:

```
ProductName, Brand, Count
TV, Samsung, 2
TV, Sony, 1
Phone, Sony, 1
```

Can you help?

Sorry I'm writing on a phone and on the bus that's why I didn't specify but please feel free to ask if you didn't understand.

Comment: This is really basic aggregation, any SQL tutorial should explain how to do it.

Comment: What have you done so far???  Try Google

Comment: Thanks! Wouldn't ask here if I found on Google, with all due respect. Was trying to use distinct but realized it was unnecessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you are looking for GROUP BY: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp

Give this a try:

```
 SELECT ProductName, Brand, count(id) AS Count FROM products GROUP BY ProductName, Brand
```

Comment: Thanks! Am giving you the correct answer for the quickness.

Answer (score 3):

Easy with Group by

```
SELECT productName, Brand, COUNT(*)
FROM yourdb
GROUP BY productName, Brand
```

Comment: Thanks! Was using distinct but I've realized it is unnecessary.